# How do I set up a Just Cause 2 Multiplayer server?

Tags: just-cause-2-multiplayer

I want to play Just Cause 2 Multiplayer with friends over LAN. What's the easiest way of setting it up, or what options do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to play on LAN with a couple of friends, that's fine. The easiest way to do this is run the server through Steam (the computer you are playing on is fine).

If you open up Steam and go "Library > Tools" and find "Just Cause 2: Multiplayer - Dedicated Server. Download and install the the location of your choice.

Once that's finished, navigate to the folder it was downloaded to, probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Just Cause 2 - Multiplayer Dedicated Server` or `C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Just Cause 2 - Multiplayer Dedicated Server`.

If you want to use the sample scripts with the server, rename (or copy) the default_scripts folder to scripts. This will be where you load any other scripts into the server. The default scripts gives you the Destruction Derby, Freeroam (teleports and spawn locations), Help (F5 help menu), Hijack_Blocker (does what it says on the tin), Killfeed (shows the list of deaths as they roll past), Localchat (gives the ability to view local-only chat or global chat), Nametags (view players names), Playerlist (shows player list and pings with F6), and Speedomether (shows your speed next to your vehicle).

Open up the config.lua file (with something like Notepad++) and configure the settings as you wish - max players, port to listen to (default 7777, no need to change this normally), server name, and a password if you want one.

The other settings are left fine as they are.

Now double-click JcmpServer.exe to launch the server. You should see any scripts get loaded. You may need to allow Jcmpserver.exe through Windows Firewall.

If you're running the server on the machine you're playing on, launch the mod client, and on "quick connect" type 127.0.0.1 in the address box. This will connect to the local machine (where your server is running).

For your friends to play, you'll need to find out your computer's IP. This can be done through Start > Run > type `cmd` and press enter, and then type ipconfig and press enter. Your IP will appear, typically starting with 192.168.x.x. You can then give this to your friends to play with over LAN.

If you want to add scripts to the running game you can copy them to the "scripts" folder and then type `load name` into the server console where `name` is the name of the script folder. Eg, if I wanted to add a message of the day command, I'd find the script on the forum, download it, extract it, copy to scripts, and then `import motd`. If you don't want to do this, stop the server by typing x and pressing enter, then starting it up again.

If you want to expose your server to the internet, you'll have to open up your router's homepage and portforward UDP port 7777 to your IP address. Then you'll need to find out what your external IP is (Google "my external IP" and that will likely tell you). Give this to people that you want to play with online and they can connect to your server.

Comment: "If you want to add scripts to the running game you can copy them to the "scripts" folder and then type `load name` into the server console where `name` is the name of the script folder. Eg, if I wanted to add a message of the day command, I'd find the script on the forum, download it, extract it, copy to scripts, and then `import motd`." -- I'm confused, are you talking about the `load` or `import` command here?